# Liferay add resource permission to DLFolder

Tags: liferay, directory, actionlistener, liferay-6

I try add resource permission to every folder that is created in the portal with the custom listener, with permission to ACCESS for the role "Guest" but in the table of database is not registered successfully, 
Is registered only the permissions for the role with action id 0, I try with this:

```
public void onAfterCreate(DLFolder folder) throws ModelListenerException {
    super.onAfterCreate(folder);
    long folderId = folder.getFolderId();
    primFOLDER = folderId;
    try {
        long guestId = RoleServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.GUEST).getRoleId();
        ResourcePermission resourcePermission = ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil
                .createResourcePermission(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
        resourcePermission.setCompanyId(companyId);
        resourcePermission.setName(folderClass);
        resourcePermission.setScope(ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL);
        resourcePermission.setPrimKey(String.valueOf(folderId));
        resourcePermission.setRoleId(guestId);
        resourcePermission.setActionIds(2);
        ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(resourcePermission);
        ResourcePermission resourcePermissionRecover = ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getResourcePermission(
                companyId, folderClass, ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL, String.valueOf(folderId), guestId);
        if (resourcePermissionRecover != null) {
            resourcePermissionRecover.setActionIds(2);
            ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.updateResourcePermission(resourcePermissionRecover);
        }
    } catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't know which is my error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this link:
https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/86705430